# python csv file elements sorting and omit duplicate

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, duplicates

I have written a python script that creates a text file containing three rows of numbers as such;

```
4.54 67.66 71.27 NaN ,4.54 304.53
9.06 14.08 39.56 NaN ,4.54 307.65
3.85 61.22 90.14 108.13 ,6.13 400.50
```

It is a concatenated dataframe resulted from different text files. There will be loads of repetitive numbers, some empty elements, etc. so I would like to sort them in ascending order and get rid of all duplicates.

For sorting, I have tried to use `df.sort_values`, but couldn't figure out how to sort values; row by row in ascending order regardless of the column name or so..

For duplicates, I originally searched for pandas to deal with this matter(e.g., `df.drop_duplicates`, transpose the data then select duplicates/re-indexing etc); but **I want to get rid of duplicated values in each row only**...I've been stuck in the same place for days already and deleting the duplicates manually by using excel. Would there be any method I can use for this matter?

Thank you in advance for any help you can offer!

Comment: What does it mean to “get rid of” a duplicate in a row? Change the duplicate cell to `null`? `NaN`?

Comment: "transpose the data" Are you saying that you this text file is saved "backwards" like it's row/column not column//row?

Comment: Ohhhhh, wait. I think he's trying to remove if any column needs to be considered separate. Like each colums as a table? Am I way off?

Comment: @Jaba I'm trying to remove any duplicate cell/entries of each row; considered separate. and for the "transpose" part, yes, it is a dataset picked up from a set of txt files(so semi-final data = concat in columns) and the final outcome should be saved in 3 rows; hence I transposed it all. apologies for any confusion caused!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the columns bear no specific meaning, it is probably easier to just drop down to NumPy arrays. In particular, you could use [`pd.Series.drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html) to get rid of the duplicated entries row-by-row, then just use `np.sort` to perform the sorting:

```
In [152]: df
Out[152]:
      0      1      2       3     4       5
0  4.54  67.66  71.27     NaN  4.54  304.53
1  9.06  14.08  39.56     NaN  4.54  307.65
2  3.85  61.22  90.14  108.13  6.13  400.50

In [153]: np.sort(df.apply(lambda x: x.drop_duplicates(), axis=1))
Out[153]:
array([[  4.54,  67.66,  71.27, 304.53,    nan,    nan],
       [  4.54,   9.06,  14.08,  39.56, 307.65,    nan],
       [  3.85,   6.13,  61.22,  90.14, 108.13, 400.5 ]])
```

If relevant, you can of course turn the result back into a `pd.DataFrame`. If one prefers, the row-wise deduplication can also be written `df.apply(pd.Series.drop_duplicates, axis=1)`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have applied this to the script and the result shows the first row being '0,1' and the rest(2&3rd rows) are not sorted.. any advice?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow: For a different set of inputs, you mean? In the example above, each individual row is sorted.

Comment: nvm, I have sorted it out some how(assume that it caused because of dtype). Thank you very much!! you are a lifesaver :)!!!